# CSS mask trick to design the tshirt with drag and resizable feature

Tags: reactjs, css-mask

I am trying to build react components to design a product dynamically where user can choose the product like tshirt, mug, jacket etc. and choose the image to print on that product base. At first I am trying to achieve image mask on the product base. I have used react dragabble and resizeable components for the choosen image. Here is the codes:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-draggable-and-resizable-pictures-3uufjl?file=index.js
I am trying to hide the choosen image if it comes outside the boundry of the tshirt when user drag or resize the image. I have researched into the css mask where background image and mask image is applied into same elements but I have background image (i.e. tshirt ) and mask image (i.e. monalisa image) which is in different html elements. I am bit confused how can I achieve the css mask image of the tshirt with the choose picture.